# global store plugin error with vue 3 condition

Tags: vue.js

With vue 3, I have state actions in different files globally, but they do not perform the necessary checks in the vue connector. I don't understand where I am doing wrong. I will be happy if you help.

I am waiting for your help to see the mistakes I have made. I am open to any comments.
app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

import {createApp} from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue'

import WebsiteRouter from './Website/router';
import AdminRouter from './Admin/router';
import ApplicationRouter from './Application/router';
import store from './store';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

store.dispatch('getUser').then(() => {
    createApp(App)
        .use(chanceRoute())
        .use(store)
        .use(DashboardPlugin)
        .mount("#app");
})
```

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

import app from './app'
import appConfig from './app-config'

export default new createStore({
    modules: {
        app,
        appConfig,
    }
})
```

app\index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import sharedMutations from 'vuex-shared-mutations';

export default {
    state: {
        user: null
    },
    getters: {
        user(state) {
            return state.user;
        },
        verified(state) {
            if (state.user) return state.user.email_verified_at
            return null
        },
        id(state) {
            if (state.user) return state.user.id
            return null
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setUser(state, payload) {
            state.user = payload;
        }
    },

    actions: {

        async login({dispatch}, payload) {
            try {
                await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');

                await axios.post('/api/login', payload).then((res) => {
                    return dispatch('getUser');
                }).catch((err) => {
                    throw err.response
                });

            } catch (e) {
                throw e
            }

        },

        async register({dispatch}, payload) {
            try {

                await axios.post('/api/register', payload).then((res) => {
                    return dispatch('login', {'email': payload.email, 'password': payload.password})
                }).catch((err) => {
                    throw(err.response)
                })
            } catch (e) {
                throw (e)
            }
        },
        async logout({commit}) {
            await axios.post('/api/logout').then((res) => {
                commit('setUser', null);
            }).catch((err) => {

            })

        },
        async getUser({commit}) {
            await axios.get('/api/user').then((res) => {
                commit('setUser', res.data);
            }).catch((err) => {

            })
        },
        async profile({commit}, payload) {
            await axios.patch('/api/profile', payload).then((res) => {
                commit('setUser', res.data.user);
            }).catch((err) => {
                throw err.response
            })
        },
        async password({commit}, payload) {
            await axios.patch('/api/password', payload).then((res) => {

            }).catch((err) => {
                throw err.response
            })
        },

        async verifyResend({dispatch}, payload) {
            let res = await axios.post('/api/verify-resend', payload)
            if (res.status != 200) throw res
            return res
        },
        async verifyEmail({dispatch}, payload) {
            let res = await axios.post('/api/verify-email/' + payload.id + '/' + payload.hash)
            if (res.status != 200) throw res
            dispatch('getUser')
            return res

        },


    },
    plugins: [sharedMutations({predicate: ['setUser']})],
    
}
```

app-config\index.js

```
import { $themeConfig } from '../../themeConfig'

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        layout: {
            isRTL: $themeConfig.layout.isRTL,
            skin: localStorage.getItem('skin') || $themeConfig.layout.skin,
            routerTransition: $themeConfig.layout.routerTransition,
            type: $themeConfig.layout.type,
            contentWidth: $themeConfig.layout.contentWidth,
            menu: {
                hidden: $themeConfig.layout.menu.hidden,
            },
            navbar: {
                type: $themeConfig.layout.navbar.type,
                backgroundColor: $themeConfig.layout.navbar.backgroundColor,
            },
            footer: {
                type: $themeConfig.layout.footer.type,
            },
        },
    },
    getters: {},
    mutations: {
        TOGGLE_RTL(state) {
            state.layout.isRTL = !state.layout.isRTL
            document.documentElement.setAttribute('dir', state.layout.isRTL ? 'rtl' : 'ltr')
        },
        UPDATE_SKIN(state, skin) {
            state.layout.skin = skin

            // Update value in localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('skin', skin)

            // Update DOM for dark-layout
            if (skin === 'dark') document.body.classList.add('dark-layout')
            else if (document.body.className.match('dark-layout')) document.body.classList.remove('dark-layout')
        },
        UPDATE_ROUTER_TRANSITION(state, val) {
            state.layout.routerTransition = val
        },
        UPDATE_LAYOUT_TYPE(state, val) {
            state.layout.type = val
        },
        UPDATE_CONTENT_WIDTH(state, val) {
            state.layout.contentWidth = val
        },
        UPDATE_NAV_MENU_HIDDEN(state, val) {
            state.layout.menu.hidden = val
        },
        UPDATE_NAVBAR_CONFIG(state, obj) {
            Object.assign(state.layout.navbar, obj)
        },
        UPDATE_FOOTER_CONFIG(state, obj) {
            Object.assign(state.layout.footer, obj)
        },
    },
    actions: {},
}
```

Comment: "error" - what error?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../store/app'

Comment: I'm going to use a different store, can you create an example for this?

Comment: There's no file that uses ../../store/app in the code that you provided. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. Currently it looks like exactly what it says, there's no module in the place where you expect it

Comment: i will update the question